Custom Multiselect Editor integration with AG Grid getValue() Problem
import React, { useState, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import type { ICellEditorParams } from "ag-grid-community";
import type { ICellEditorReactComp } from "ag-grid-react";

interface OptionType {
    label: string;
    value: { id: string | number }; // Allow id to be string or number
}

interface AgGridMultiSelectEditorParams extends ICellEditorParams {
    values: OptionType[]; // Array of relation records formatted for react-select
}

interface AgGridMultiSelectEditorRef extends ICellEditorReactComp {
    getValue: () => OptionType[]; // Assuming you're returning OptionType[]
}

const AgGridMultiSelectEditor = forwardRef<AgGridMultiSelectEditorRef, AgGridMultiSelectEditorParams>(
    (props, ref) => {
        const [selectedRecords, setSelectedRecords] = useState<OptionType[]>([]);  // Initialize with an empty array
        const inputRef = useRef(null);  // This will help manage react-select focus
        console.log("Editor ref:", ref);

        // When the component mounts, ensure react-select is focused
        useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
            console.log("useImperativeHandle triggered");
            return {
                getValue: () => {
                    console.log("getValue called. Selected records:", selectedRecords);
                    return selectedRecords;
                },
                isPopup: () => true,
                afterGuiAttached: () => {
                    console.log("Editor attached");
                    inputRef.current?.focus();  // Focus react-select when the editor is attached
                }
            };
        });


        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("Component mounted");
            return () => {
                console.log("Component unmounted");
            };
        }, []);

        return (
            <Select
                ref={inputRef}  // Use the inputRef for handling focus
                value={selectedRecords}  // Bind selectedRecords to the value prop
                // onChange={(newSelected) => {
                //     console.log("Selected values:", newSelected);  // Log selected values
                //     setSelectedRecords(newSelected || []);  // Update state on change
                // }}
                onChange={(newSelected) => {
                    setSelectedRecords(newSelected || []);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        props.api.stopEditing();  // Forcefully tell ag-Grid to stop editing and call getValue()
                    }, 2000);
                }}
                options={props.values}  // Pass available options from props
                isMulti  // Enable multi-select
            />
        );
    }
);

export default AgGridMultiSelectEditor;

The code above is a custom react-select multiselect editor that i'm passing it into agGrid, through column definitions. I have everything set up correctly. In editing mode, i can open up the react-select component, and it shows me all the correct values with no problem on selection. Things I selected also logs out perfectly through the useEffect.
To my understanding, when editing ends, agGrid would then use its getValue method automatically to capture the value changed. In simpler editors like an input, agGrid seems to bypass the need for this. But for more complex editors like multiselect, I'm overriding getValue to return what i want with more specifications. So here's the problem. Even though adding console logging to imperitavehandle shows the handle is called, getValue() never logs anything. Everything I select never pass through to agGrid. I have event listener logger set up for cell editing start, cell changed, cell editing stopped. In this case, editing start and end works. But the end value shows both old and new value to be undefined.
What seems to be the problem here? I also tried manually triggering the cell edit end with props.api.stopEditing();, this doesn't work either.
Here's a link to an example that integrated sucessfully mantine multiselect with ag-grid. Different select editor, but the concept should be the same on interacting with agGrid. The sandbox code is provided within the article. It's imperativeHandle's override getValue() gets called and passes the value to agGrid correctly. I can't seem to find what I'd doing different or wrong with my own getValue() implementation.
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-how-to-implement-custom-multiselect-cell-editor-in-aggrid-9b5470ecd0eb

I found the solution. The problem is that my code and the example I'm following is using ag-grid 30's implementation. Latest ag-grid is v32, and it uses a whole new method.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/f7scdz
Instead of passing ref, you're now passing only props: CustomCellEditorProps. And all you need essentailly are

value: for the values you passed to your cellEditorParams
onValueChange: to set your selected value(s)
stopEditing: to tell ag-grid you're done editing and pass the values you set to it.

The example doesn't show you how to keep track of your component focus, as you'll need it if you're going to implement multiselect. You don't want to call stopEditing() on your select component's onchange. Here's a sample on how to set up tracking your component's focus, and call stopEditing() when it's out of focus, and ag-grid will handle the rest.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, memo } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import type { CustomCellEditorProps } from '@ag-grid-community/react';

export const FontierEditor = memo(({ values, onValueChange, stopEditing }: CustomCellEditorProps) => {
    const [selectedRecords, setSelectedRecords] = useState([]);
    const refContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleFocusOut = (event: FocusEvent) => {
            if (refContainer.current && !refContainer.current.contains(event.relatedTarget as Node)) {
                // Detect when the focus moves away from the select editor
                stopEditing();
            }
        };

        // Add the focus out listener
        const container = refContainer.current;
        if (container) {
            container.addEventListener('focusout', handleFocusOut);
        }

        // Cleanup the event listener on component unmount
        return () => {
            if (container) {
                container.removeEventListener('focusout', handleFocusOut);
            }
        };
    }, [stopEditing]);

    return (
        <div ref={refContainer}>
            <Select
                value={selectedRecords}
                onChange={(newSelected) => {
                    setSelectedRecords(newSelected); // Keep selected values in the state
                    onValueChange(newSelected.map(record => record.value) || []);
                }}
                options={values}
                isMulti
            />
        </div>
    );
});

